# Cannot reference Label with Dynamically Generated ID with ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have a page that queries a DB and displays information for a number of printers. I have several sections that I would like to update at different intervals client-side using AJAX (at least this is best solution my research has come up with). I can get AJAX itself to work with the common "Show the time" example without any issues.

My problem is that the IDs if the sections I want to update (I've tried span, asp:label, div...> are generated with the server side code and ends up something like "Label1", "Label2"...

Every time I try to update the text inside one of these generated labels I get "'Label1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level". Everything is within a form tag, everything is "runat="server"". I feel like I'm just missing a setting, or a reference to something. So far I haven't been able to narrow my searching enough to get a useful answer.

I've lurked around here for years and have always been able to find a solution. This has me stumped though.

---- Example -----

The end goal is to have better control of when and how specific elements are updated. This is using the Timer tutorial demo. In my application I would be assigning IDs for the labels based on a record ID from a query (i.e. ID = "Mach" & MID)

The original code that works as posted:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <!--  Ajax button code start -->
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Ajax - Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <!--  Ajax button code end -->
    <br /><br />
    <!--  Non - Ajax button code start -->
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Non - Ajax - Button" onclick="Button2_Click" />
    <!--  Non - Ajax button code end -->
</div>
</form>
```

And the Code Behind

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Sub
```

It seems to me the follow should work the same way:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<% Call Generated()%>
</div>
</form>
```

Code Behind:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Sub

Public Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
    Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString()
End Sub

Public Sub Generated()
    Dim str As String

    str = "<div>"
    str = str & ("<asp:ScriptManager ID=""ScriptManager1"" runat=""server"" />")
    str = str & ("<asp:UpdatePanel ID=""UpdatePanel1"" runat=""server"">")
    str = str & ("<ContentTemplate>")
    str = str & ("<asp:Label ID=""Label1"" runat=""server"" Text=""Label""></asp:Label>")
    str = str & ("<asp:Button ID=""Button1"" runat=""server"" Text=""Ajax - Button"" onclick=""Button1_Click"" />")
    str = str & ("</ContentTemplate>")
    str = str & ("</asp:UpdatePanel>")
    str = str & ("<br /><br />")
    str = str & ("<asp:Label ID=""Label2"" runat=""server"" Text=""Label""></asp:Label>")
    str = str & ("<asp:Button ID=""Button2"" runat=""server"" Text=""Non - Ajax - Button"" onclick=""Button2_Click"" />")
    str = str & ("</div>")
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Id of dynamically added control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160126/get-id-of-dynamically-added-control)

Comment: You need to show your code. Include relevant C# and markup. Get enough code to convey the problem, but no more. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).